# Can we restrict records that are visible to a profile using custom Apex Sharing rules?

Tags: sharing, apex-sharing

How can we restrict 1 particular Opportunity record type records using Apex Sharing rules for a profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

**Sharing is to grant access not restrict it.**

The only way to restrict record is using OWD.

The easiest way to think about it is:

> If even ONE person should not have access to any single record of an object then
>   the OWD for that object must be set to Private.

Access is then granted by all of the various sharing rules, criteria etc.

So in your case,

1. OWD would be private
2. Sharing rules for all Opps except that record type would be shared with everyone (or whoever you need to)
3. Opps of that record type would be shared only with the groups/roles you desire and not with those who should not have access

If your OWD is already public you will need to evaluate the effects before you change it to private

Answer (score 0):

Make opportunity private, make only the record type you want available in the profile setting, then create a [Sharing based criteria](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_cbs_about.htm) and share all records which has that record type to either a specific Role or Public Group, but you won't be able to share to a profile. If you have multiple roles that group that profile, better to create a public group and add all the roles your need. It will depend on your specific case and your role hierarchy 
[image]